software updater settings giving a long error that doesn't fit into my screen!
I have recently upgraded from 22.04.4 to 24.04.1 and when I open software updater settings and change some settings and the click close an then reload it opens a dialogue named "refreshing software cache" and then gives a big error dialogue that doesn't fit into the screen.If anyone wants to see the screen recording go here.
and the i did "sudo apt-get update" into the terminal and this is what it spited out this
how can I fix this?
Update:As i am living in Iran I changed my server to main server and then turned on my vpn .now gnome "software and updates " doesn't give that long error but still running "sudo apt-get update"
would give the same long error.

This question is similar to: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry after installing Ubuntu 24.04 and How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The error is:
Err:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu noble Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]

That repository / ppa doesn't exits or is down.
You can try to open the url in a browser an see if it's alive and if it supports Noble under the dists link - It is, and it doesn't
Or you can disable it in Software Settings.

It didn't change anything

What didn't change anything ?

I removed the software repository as you told me and then the long error message (warning maybe) still appears.

Please update the question with a new output of  'sudo apt update'

"sudo apt-get update" gives this error : https://pastebin.com/DymTBKdM

Those are other/ new errors. The repository you removed don't error now. The errors are self explaining, some repos are defined more than one time and in what file: line number. Mostly /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources it seems. Remove lines one at the time and run 'sudo apt update after to verify that the error has gone. Eventually you can remove more lines at the time if you are sure they are doublets. It might be a good idea to make a copy of the file in case you break something.
